# Does Xamarin.Forms Carousel View uses virtualization to achieve performance?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to know if there is any performance strategy on Carousel View like Recycler View on Android or UICollection on iOS. It seems they use virtualization of the items to achive performance, but i'm not sure if Carousel View uses that approach.

I'm afraid to use this component with a collection of 50 items.

I found this answer [CarouselView issue answer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9200#issuecomment-643822589) but it still not cleary for me since there is nothing on the documentation about it.

Comment: We could use pagination(when scroll to last item load the next five or ten items) when loading large number of items .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, `CarouselView` was added as the side effect of adding `CollectionView` which uses the underlying controls that you mention.